# Where to get documentation on and/or source of SQL Server Migration Assistant extended procedures?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-migration-assi, extended-procedures

I am running into login timeout errors while calling a procedure that uses `xp_ora2ms_exec2_ex` through JDBC.  There's nothing in the SQL Server Profiler trace log.  The DB was restored from a back-up.  I'm wondering if some setting did not get restored.  I need to know what it is that `xp_ora2ms_exec2_ex` does exactly to check the settings.  The error isn't encountered when calling the same procedure through `sqlcmd`.

Comment: specifically `xp_ora2ms_exec2_ex` was implemented in native code and source is not available https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aa2c43ef-6056-49cb-99de-24fdf2d40863/xpora2msexec2-missing-in-master?forum=sqlservermigration

Comment: I believe original purpose was to help with some limitations of stored functions (not procedures!) in SQL Server when translating from Oracle (probably related to https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/#sixth )